# Avoid null results from query

Tags: php, mysql

suppose this

user table:
[id] [mail] [pass]

happen table:
[id] [uid] [date] [content]

vote table
[uid] [hid] [type] [datetime]

1 user can have 0 or more happen, 1 happen can have 0 or more votes..

I want to get the total number of votes for a specific happen

```
SELECT
 H.*,
 SUM(CASE WHEN V.type='C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS upvotes,
 SUM(CASE WHEN V.type='R' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS downvotes
FROM
 happens H
LEFT JOIN
 votes AS V
 ON V.hid = H.id
WHERE
 H.uid = :uid
```

the problem is that if no votes is associated on a happen I get a null row from mysql, not EMPTY but NULL

how can I avoid this null result?

[edit]

some try:

basic

```
SELECT H.* FROM happens H LEFT JOIN votes AS V ON V.hid = H.id WHERE H.uid = '178d937'
```

result -> empty

All other try with the SUM, COUNT, HAVING ect ect gives:

```
[id] [uid] [what] [latitude] [longitude] [date] [time] [hide] [upvotes] [downvotes]
NULL NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    0   0
```

Comment: try this, instead of using `SUM` use `COUNT`. eg, `COUNT(CASE WHEN V.type='C' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)`

Comment: id uid what latitude longitude date time hide upvotes downvotes
NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 0 0

Answer (score 1):

Use `HAVING` to check for the null

```
SELECT
 H.*,
 SUM(CASE WHEN V.type='C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS upvotes,
 SUM(CASE WHEN V.type='R' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS downvotes
FROM
 happens H
LEFT JOIN
 votes AS V
 ON V.hid = H.id
WHERE
 H.uid = :uid
HAVING upvotes IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I'm sorry, now on users with some happen and some votes I get only 1 row even if there's 4/5 rows to display.....

Comment: I have provided having as `HAVING upvotes IS NOT NULL` not on `H.id`  and can you share the sqlfiddle with us with some sample data

Comment: yess hope this work, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0872/5 here the second query have to display 3 rows not 1

Comment: Try this one http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0872/6 let me know if this you are looking for

Comment: @Mindexperiment The fiddle i have provided have 2 rows because the user **52343bd76e367** has 2 happens and these 2 happens have 3 votes `SUM()` is an aggregate function and when used there should be a group in first fiddle you are seeing 1 row because use of sum() without group by and second fiddle is correct you want the sum of each happen so as i already stated user **52343bd76e367** has only 2 happens so there will be only two rows,I hope you got my point

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT H.*,
    SUM(IFNULL(V.type = 'C', 0)) AS upvotes,
    SUM(IFNULL(V.type = 'R', 0)) AS downvotes
```

Comment: the null values are on the result set not on the vote table... the query returns null fieldss

Answer (score 1):

If you change your LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN (or just JOIN) you will only get the happens records that have at least 1 associated record in the votes table:

```
SELECT
 H.*,
 SUM(CASE WHEN V.type='C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS upvotes,
 SUM(CASE WHEN V.type='R' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS downvotes
FROM
 happens H
INNER JOIN
 votes AS V
 ON V.hid = H.id
WHERE
 H.uid = :uid
```

Check out http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp for info on the different join types.

**EDIT:**

Ok, so to get all happens, but with 0 for those without votes try (add COALESCE):

```
SELECT
 H.*,
 COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN V.type='C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) AS upvotes,
 COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN V.type='R' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) AS downvotes
FROM
 happens H
LEFT JOIN
 votes AS V
 ON V.hid = H.id
WHERE
 H.uid = :uid
```

Comment: just try but same result... maybe the problem is on the H.* ??? because I'm trying to get the result from a user that has not happen added...

Comment: You should get an empty result for a user that doesn't have anything in your happen table with the above. It's possible to return a row for the user even if there are no records in happen, with counts of 0 for votes, but there won't be any happen data to associate it to (all of the happen fields will be NULL), so I'm not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: user can add happen, every hapen can be voted by other user. I need to display on the user page every user's happen. If the happen has some votes associated diplay the number of upvotes and downvotes.

Comment: the dianuj solution works but it give me only 1 row even if a user has many happen..mmmmmm

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
 H.*,
 COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN V.type='C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS upvotes,
 COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN V.type='R' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS downvotes
```

Answer (score 0):

Left Join will return all rows on the left and NULL values on the right if ON condition does not match.Use Inner Join.

Comment: already try with INNER JOIN but always the same result... a row with NULL values

Comment: @Mindexperiment Can you post some result sample?

Answer (score 0):

solved using 2 statement

1. first select all happen
2. second select all votes for every happen and merging the values

here is the solution from my php happenModel class:

```
public function getUserHappensWithVotes() {
$selectQuery = <<<QUERY
SELECT
 SUM(CASE WHEN V.type='C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS upvotes,
 SUM(CASE WHEN V.type='R' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS downvotes
FROM
 votes V
WHERE
 V.uid = :uid
AND
 V.hid = :hid
QUERY;

    // get all happen as array of class
    $userHappens = $this->userHappens;
    // empty container
    $happenWithVotes = array();

    foreach( $userHappens AS $happen ) {
        $sql = $this->pdo->prepare( $selectQuery );
        $sql->execute( array( ':uid'=>$happen->uid, ':hid'=>$happen->id ) );

        // fetching the count of up and down votes of every happen
        $votes = $sql->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
        // merging happen class as array with votes
        $happen = array_merge( (array) $happen, $votes );

        // rebuild the userHappen array
        $happenWithVotes[] = (object) $happen;
    }

    if ( $this->encoder ) {
        return $this->encoder->setData( $this->parse( $happenWithVotes ) )->encode();
        } else {
        return $this->parse( $happenWithVotes );
    }
}
```